# INSERTAR UN VALOR EN UNA TABLA MEDIANTE PROCEDIMIENTO ORACLE

Tags: oracle

por favor si pueden ayudarme.
tengo una tabla llamada PRODUCTO, en la cual ya hay un campo que se llama "PRECIO".  quiero calcular en otro campo de esta misma tabla el margen de ganancia. mediante un procedimiento. por ejemplo, que el precio sea multiplicado por 0.3 y lo ingrese en el atributo MARGEN.

Saludos y gracias

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y leas :  [ask] para que te podamos ayudar y evites votos negativos.

Answer (score 0):

Es igual como si fueras a insertar usando la consola o sentencia SQL por ejemplo:

```
insert into PRODUCTO values (variablePrecio, variablePrecio*0.3);
```

Ya tu decides su si quieres pasar el valor directo a una variable como en el ejemplo o se manera estatica.